# How do you save and retrieve an image to and from MySQL database using javafx?

Tags: java

I am developing a minor app that will require a user to add and view products which includes use of images. How do I save and retrieve the image using javafx?

I know how select the image using a file chooser and display it using the absolute path but on saving, the absolute path has no slashes thus had to view the image when you retrieve the path from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here:

1. Insert the image as a BLOB column in your database.
2. Save the image file to a known location on the file system and insert the path to that file into your database.

Comment: Thank you. I used the blob data type in the database I guess it requires some conversation to save the image. That's where I want assistance

Comment: @Wachiye Please edit your question to show what you have done so far.